# asp.net core 2.2 razor page login not persistent. very soon user must re login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

**user after login very soon exit and must be re login.**

i want user persistent in site for 30 minutes after login.

in startup:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
})
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Configure your policies
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    options.AddPolicy("PanelPolicy", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole("admin")
));

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

and in login page:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

but after short second user must re login to site

Comment: You can find information how to set expiration in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @kyziur i set that.  options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i using shared hosting. When the program in iis is restarted, a new key is created. Therefore the previous token becomes invalid. So we have to manage the key to be valid with the reset

this line solve my problem

```
services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code instead

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Or

```
services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
    });
```